# Django REST API TestCase Normalize Email failing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, testcase

I keep failing a test case that tests whether the email passed into the `create_user` function is  normalized correctly. However the `normalize_email()` method does not seem to be working properly.

**test_modles.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


    class ModelTests(TestCase):
    
        def test_new_user_email_normalized(self):
            """Test the email for a new user is normalized"""
            email = 'TEST.TES.com'
            user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
                email,
                'test1213'
            )
    
            self.assertEqual(user.email, email.lower())
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, \
                                        PermissionsMixin


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves a new user"""

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custome user model that supports using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_teamMember = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

**error**

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_new_user_email_normalized (core.tests.test_models.ModelTests)
Test the email for a new user is normalized
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/core/tests/test_models.py", line 27, in test_new_user_email_normalized
    self.assertEqual(user.email, email.lower())
AssertionError: 'TEST.TES.com' != 'test.tes.com'
- TEST.TES.com
+ test.tes.com


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.484s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error

```
def test_new_user_email_normalized(self):
            """Test the email for a new user is normalized"""
            email = 'TEST.TES.com' #<------------ Error Here -------
            user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
                email,
                'test1213'
            )
```

should be

`email = 'test@tes.com'`